# 64-Bit OLEDB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL) issues

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to create a Linked Server from SQL 2008 SP1 64 bit instance located on a Windows 64 bit 2003 SP2 server towards a Mysql Server. As many of you know MSDASQL provider for 64 bit systems was put available by Microsoft later [in a hot fix.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=000364db-5e8b-44a8-b9be-ca44d18b059b) This is what I have done so far:

1. Install MySQL connector.
2. Install MSDASQL provider.
3. Create ODBC connection with correct credentials. Test is succesfull.

When I try to create a Linked Server specifying the new DSN created I get the following error:

> Cannot initialize the data source
>   object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "MYSQL". OLE DB
>   provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
>   "MYSQL" returned message "Specified
>   driver could not be loaded due to
>   system error  998 (MySQL ODBC 5.1
>   Driver).". (Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Error: 7303)

I mention that **I didn't reboot** the server after installing the hotfix containing the OLEDB provider since it is a Production server and I must have a very good reason for doing this. Is the restart required?

I installed process monitor and I saw that before throwing the error SQL tries to get access to two paths:

Path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.1\myodbc5.dll.2.Config
Result: NAME NOT FOUND

Path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\share\charsets\
Result: NAME NOT FOUND

I gave full rights on C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.1 to user which tries to get the access.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't want to reboot a prod server, but you didn't test it first on another server?

Comment: I don't know much about this . But i've come across a good article : http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have another test server with windows 2003 server on 64 bit. We have upgraded all our servers to windows 2008 and this is the single one left.

Comment: Can you use the driver through the ODBC manager?  If not a reboot may be needed.  Without another server to test on, I'd recommend biting the bullet and seeing if that does the trick.  When you try the ODBC manager try turning on the ODBC trace and see what that reports.

Comment: @mrdenny: Yes I can connect to MYSQL database through ODBC manager... the driver should work then.

Comment: @yrushka, yes it should work then. Try turning on ODBC tracing and see what is captured when you make the call through the linked server.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just read this on a blog. YMMV

http://www.ryanjadams.com/2011/03/dsn-windows-64bit/

Comment: THANKS, I tested - no success for me. I used eventually a different server to setup the Linked Server on a Windows 2008 server. I don't know why it didn't work, most probably some registry key is messed up and does not read the dll file. I am marking the question fixed.